# Media queries not working for iPhone series

Tags: ios, css, iphone

I wrote media queries for `iPhone 4/4S`, `iPhone 5/5S`, `iPhone 6` and `iPhone 6Plus`. 
Here is the code:

```
/*For iPhone 4/4S*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation: portrait){ /*my styles here */ }
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation: landscape){ /*my styles here */ }  

/*For iPhone 6*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width : 667px) and (orientation : portrait) {  /*my styles here */ }
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width : 667px) and (orientation : landscape) {  /*my styles here */ }

/*For iPhone 6plus*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 
736px) and (orientation : portrait) { /*my styles here */ }
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 736px) and (orientation : landscape) { /*my styles here */ }
```

For `portrait mode`, each device's portrait `css` gets applied successfully. But for `landscape mode` of all devices, only landscape media query of `iPhone 6Plus` is getting applied.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to apply a set of styles if the viewing device either had a minimum width of 700px or was a handheld in landscape, you could write the following:

```
@media (min-width: 700px), handheld and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Above, if I were on a screen device with a viewport width of 800px, the media statement would return true because the first part, interpreted as @media all and (min-width: 700px) would apply to my device and therefore return true, despite the fact that my screen device would fail the handheld media type check in the second media query. Likewise, if I were on a handheld device held in landscape with a viewport width of 500px, while the first media query would fail due to the viewport width, the second media query would succeed and thus the media statement would return true.

> **comma-separated lists**
>
> Comma-separated lists behave like the logical operator or when used in
>   media queries. When using a comma-separated list of media queries, if
>   any of the media queries returns true, the styles or style sheets get
>   applied. Each media query in a comma-separated list is treated as an
>   individual query, and any operator applied to one media query does not
>   affect the others. This means the comma-separated media queries can
>   target different media features, types, and states.

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: It seems that you've copied all from that reference. Can I use media query like this? 
`@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px), handheld and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {`

Comment: yes, I copied that and provided the reference below. Well you can usr all the logical operators provided you use it correctly.

Comment: Okay... 
I'd  use it like this:  `@media only screen , handheld and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation: portrait) { }`